# Probability -Archie will succumb to the flu and die while he is away

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Archie must travel to a foreign country where a deadly strain of flu has ravaged the population. Already, $28$ % of the population has succumbed to the flu and died. There is a vaccine, but because the flu is extremely contagious, it spreads quite rapidly, and to date, only $10$ out of every $15$ people have been vaccinated. $Thirty-eight$ percent of those who are not vaccinated die from the flu. Archie has just enough time to be vaccinated before he leaves. What is the probability that Archie will succumb to the flu and die while he is away? Round your answer to two decimal places.

My answer:

## $(5/15)*0.38+(10/15)*P=0.28$

## $P=0.23$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Your school has some interesting math problems

Comment: yaa they do a lots of interesting math questions

Comment: your approach is correct